# How to calculate the conduction angle of a CVD diode?

Tags: diodes

*This is not a homework question, it's a textbook exercise for which the answer's already provided, I'm just not sure how to do it.*

[image]
[image]

I know that the conduction angle is the angle during which the diode is conducting. The full wave is 360 degrees, so I'd be trying to calculate what portion of that 360 degrees is conducting and what isn't. I'm not sure where to start with the trig, if someone could provide some guidance regarding how the formulas in part A are derived, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm writing this whole thing to supplement Spehro's answer. His answer is just fine. But I thought I'd add a picture, since you wrote, "I'm not sure where to start with the trig."

[image]

Hopefully, this circle rings a bell! For a sine wave voltage source, it is convenient to consider the angle \$0^{\circ}\$ in the same place that the mathematicians have used when defining the magnitude of the sine.

In the above case, your voltage source is the length of \$r\$. As the sine wave goes from \$0^{\circ}\$ to \$360^{\circ}\$, \$r\$ doesn't change at all. It's always the same size. The only thing we care about that ***does*** change, is the length of \$y\$. This is the momentary voltage from the voltage source. The equation is just:

$$y=r\cdot sin\left(\theta\right)$$

Okay. You also know, or you should, that when you are told the RMS voltage is \$X\$ then the peak voltage at the top of the sine wave must be \$\sqrt{2}X\$. That's also the magnitude for \$r\$. The only other thing you need to keep in your head is the voltage drop of the diode. That's given as \$700mV\$. So you know that when the voltage after the diode (across the resistor) just begins to exceed \$0V\$, that the value of \$y=r\cdot sin\left(\theta\right)\$ must be itself, right at that very same moment, just beginning to exceed \$700mV\$. So you set that up as an equation and follow through:

$$\begin{align*}
12V\sqrt{2}\cdot sin\left(\theta\right) &= 700mV \\
sin\left(\theta\right) &= \frac{700mV}{12V\sqrt{2}} \\
\theta &= sin^{-1}\left(\frac{700mV}{12V\sqrt{2}}\right) \approx 2.364^{\circ}
\end{align*}$$

That's the angle at which the diode just starts to conduct. That's also the angle, just prior to \$180^{\circ}\$, that the diode will cease to conduct.

Hopefully, this reminds you about the trigonometry/geometry of the situation.

Comment: This was super helpful, much like your response to my previous question on StackExchange! Thanks a lot jonk, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The conduction angle \$\phi\$ is the angle in which the diode conducts. To determine the conduction angle, we need to find out the angles at which the diode starts and ceases conduction. This occurs when $$v_s = V_D$$ 
This equality holds at two points (i.e. **A** and **B** points) as the following figure shows

[image]

At point **A**, the diode starts conducting, therefore,

$$
v_s  = V_D \\
V_s \sin\theta  = V_D \\
\theta = \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{V_D}{V_s} \right)
$$

At point **B**, the diode ceases conducting, therefore, we need to find out \$\alpha\$

$$
\alpha = \pi - ( \phi + \theta ) \\
\phi = \pi - ( \alpha + \theta )
$$

Due to the symmetry property, \$\alpha = \theta\$, the conduction angle is

$$
\phi = \pi - ( \theta + \theta ) \\
\phi = \pi - ( 2\theta )
$$

**Note:** in the preceding discussion, we assume the sinusoid as a sine wave which has led us to \$ \phi = \pi - ( 2\theta )\$. You are also allowed to choose the sinusoid as a cosine wave which will eventually lead you to \$ \phi =  2\theta \$. Both yield same conduction angle. I leave it as an exercies for you in case of cosine form.

Answer (score 2):

The conduction angle follows from the angle at which it begins (or ends) conduction, since the 2.4 degrees is subtracted from both ends of the 180 degrees, leaving you with about 175 degrees.

To get the 2.4 degrees- you know that the voltage at the input to the rectifier is \$12\sqrt{2}\sin(\theta)\$. This is a half-wave rectifier with a single diode drop, so you can solve for the angle \$\theta_b\$ when the diode first begins to conduct.

The conduction angle is then just \$180-2\theta_b\$