# What exactly does a conduction angle mean in semiconductor electronics?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors

I read a question about conduction angle at [How to calculate the conduction angle of a CVD diode?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/257293/how-to-calculate-the-conduction-angle-of-a-cvd-diode) . However, I am confused as to what is the "exact definition" of conduction angle. There are two possibilities in my mind and I'm unable to find out which one is correct

1. Angle during one full cycle (2pi) during which the rectifier is conducting?
2. Maximum length of a continuous interval in a full cycle (2pi) during which the rectifier is conducting.

I recall reading the second one somewhere, but don't know if it is true as I can't find an authentic source.

Based on these definitions, the answer to the linked question will not change, but I'm not sure whether that will be the case for other rectifiers as well.

If I am totally wrong on this matter, could you please give the definition of conduction angle. I am unable to find an authentic source.

Comment: Angle between when the rectifier starts conducting and stops conducting. For any one diode it'll happen ONCE per full cycle (2*pi) : for a bridge rectifier it'll happen twice (I'd call that the total conduction angle). Just be clear and unambiguous which you mean.

Comment: So, for the bridge rectifier, total conduction angle will be what? 2*(conduction angle)? If this is the case then I think I've got the answer to my question.

Comment: It depends why you are using 'condcuton angle'. If it's to calaculate the heat dissipated in the didoe, then it's total. If it's for some other reason, it might be either. Give us the context, and we can give you the definition.